# How to highlight only selected but not clicked?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to turn off background highlighting of text when clicking on that text. But I want to keep highlights enabled for double-clicked (selected) text.

I tried changing the `editor.selectionHighlightBackground` setting, but it affects both focused and selected text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following setting:

```
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false,
```